# How to resolve Firebird "unavailable database" error on a remote database?

Tags: .net, vb.net, firebird

I have a Firebird 2.0 database running on a remote Windows XP PC.
Using the ADO.net connection provider, I configure the connection as follows:

```
Dim x As New FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionStringBuilder
x.Database = "[hostname]:FileShare:/db/REMOTE_SVR.FDB"
x.UserID = "SYSDBA"
x.Password = "masterkey"

Dim y As New FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection(x.ConnectionString)
y.Open()
```

Attempting to open the connection raises an `FbException`, with the message "unavailable database".

Downloading the ODBC drivers and attempting to connect with those settings produces the same error message.

I have copied the database file to my development environment and verified that I can connect to `x.Database = "c:\testdb\REMOTE_SVR.FDB"` with these settings (with a local install of Firebird 2.0 Server).

I have confirmed that the Firebird 2.0 Server is running on the remote PC. The fileshare in which the DB is located doesn't require any login or permissions.

I'm probably doing something dumb, but I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firebird will - by default - not open database files that are located on a network share. The file must be on a physical disk of the server. This is done to protect the database against corruption from incorrect or insufficient locking of the file (eg when accessed by multiple Firebird server processes from different machines).

So you need to move the database to one of the real drives of the machine that hosts the Firebird server process.

Comment: Here's a link from the [Firebird manual](http://firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg2-databases.html) describing how to connect to remote databases using a valid TCP/IP connection string. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Frosty840 Yes, what you are misunderstanding is that you are connecting to a Firebird server, and the Firebird server then accesses a database local to that machine. That works. However you are connecting to a Firebird server, then you want to connect to a database located on a networkshare, that is disallowed by the Firebird process by default to prevent potential corruption.

Comment: @Frosty840 Or in other words: a Firebird database file should never be on a network share, the only way it should be "shared" is through a Firebird server process.

Comment: How then, can I connect to the Firebird server process? I have not seen any documentation for connecting to Firebird databases other than to connect directly to the FDB file...

Comment: @Frosty840 By specifying the hostname, you are connecting to the Firebird process. So `myserver:d:\database\mydatabase.fdb` will connecy to the Firebird server process on `myserver` and ask it to open the database `d:\database\mydatabase.fdb`. If `d:` is a local drive, that works, if `d:` is a network share, that fails.

Comment: Huh. `x.Database = "[hostname]:c:\FileShare\db\REMOTE_SVR.FDB"` worked immediately, exactly as you said. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Frosty840 You should really consider moving the database outside of a folder that is shared as a network drive (which I assume that `C:\FileShare` is). The database should only be accessed through the Firebird process.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a database configured by an external company, running on their machines, within our business. I am only accessing it to try and gather some data. The fact that they have configured that fileshare for direct access to that file, when it can't be used to access the database itself is very puzzling.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Your answer worked. Thank you. I had to copy the FDB from the network share to the local drive and the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not about setup connection using ADO.net, but I still try to answer how to connect to remote FDB from Windows.

1. In `firebird.conf` set `RemoteFileOpenAbility` to 1. This parameter will allow your DBMS connect to DB located in remote folder. Also check that `Redirection` parameter is set to 0 or is commented with #.
2. Download PSTools from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec, unpack it.
3. From `PSTools` folder via CMD (started as admin) execute `psexec -i -s cmd.exe`, accept agreement.
4. In popped-up CMD's window execute `whoami` to check that you are now identified as `nt authority\system`.
5. In that window execute such command:

`net use z: \\123.111.111.111\my_share /persistent:yes`, where `z` is a network drive letter, you want to assign, and `123.111.111.111\my_share` is an address of your network share. If the command executed successfully you will see new network drive in the Explorer.

If you got `System error 58`, try to execute command with specifying user/password in quotes like:

`net use z: \\123.111.111.111\my_share /persistent:yes /user:"your username" "your password"`

If in the future you will need to disconnect that network drive, perform step 3, then execute `net use z: /delete`. Or just reboot OS.

6. Now you can launch your client (ibexpert, dbeaver, etc.) and connect to remote FDB file:

- Server name: `localhost`
- FDB file path: `Z:/path_to_FDB/some_db.FDB`