# How to fix Firebird Unavailable Database exception in Win 10

Tags: firebird

> Unavailable Database

I have been trying to solve this issue. I have the database on a remote computer (my LAN). Firebird service is running. I can connect to and manage the database from my PC with EMS SQL IB/FB Manager. FlameRobin can connect to the host, but not to the database. But when my app tries to connect, I get the error.

I have ensured that the 32bit fbclient is in SysWOW folder.
The firewall has exceptions for Firebird and for port 3050.

What else can I do to fix this?

Comment: How do you connect from EMS SQL, and how are you connecting from FlameRobin? If EMS works, then so should FlameRobin. Could you please post the full error, the connection config used by EMS, FlameRobin and your application, and also check if the `firebird.log` contains errors around that time.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916008/how-to-resolve-firebird-unavailable-database-error-on-a-remote-database?rq=1

Comment: fb log: 
SSD (Client) Fri Dec 22 05:57:43 2017
 Guardian starting: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbserver.exe"

Comment: 11:47:45.990: Params = DriverID=fB
Server=localhost
Database=michelle-hp:C:\ProgramData\IAGDCS\MMPP\Data\mmpp.fdb
User_Name=sysdba
Password=masterkey

Comment: Please **edit** your question, don't use comments to add information. Also, are you using the same for EMS and FlameRobin? Note that ` Server=localhost Database=michelle-hp:C:\ProgramData\IAGDCS\MMPP\Data\mmpp.fd‌​b` looks rather suspicious, that should more likely need to be `Server=Michell-hp`, `Database=C:\ProgramData\IAGDCS\MMPP\Data\mmpp.fd‌​b`.

Comment: Are you running your app from a remote computer share? If so, check if you are using SMBv1, which became deprecated in Windows 10.